# How to remove a a space given between charcters/Words in Textbox

Tags: c#

I have a function which will removes more than one Space in the Text Box and makes the character/Word with One Space.My need is that to remove all the Spaces and make it as a Single Text, Is there a Way to do it.

The function I am using to remove Space is,

```
  public static string Removespace(string inputString)
{

    System.Text.StringBuilder strbuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    string[] spacechars = inputString.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\n', '\t', '\r', '\f', '\v' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    int size = parts.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        strbuilder.AppendFormat("{0} ", spacechars[i]);
    return strbuilder.ToString();

}
```

Comment: Why don't you remove the readded space used in the AppendFormat?

Comment: Change your `"{0} "` to `"{0}"`

Comment: [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) is all you need!!

Comment: @Soner Gonul Thanks Very Much Simpler Solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `String.Replace` method.

```
string mystring = "This is test";
mystring = mystring.Replace(" ","");
```

Or you can use the regular expression as well

```
mystring = Regex.Replace(mystring, @"\s+", "");
```

Comment: Note that the Regex version also replaces tabs and other whitespace, which the string.Replace method doesn't.

Comment: @HansKesting Could You Kindly Specify what are other white Spaces

Comment: @Rajesh - as in your original code: tab (`\t`), newline (`\n`), return (`\r`) etc.

Answer (score 4):

To replace all whitespace characters:

```
string s= "This is a test";

string s2 = new String(s.Where(c => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c)).ToArray());
```

The `Where(c => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c)` part filters out all kinds of whitespace characters. The result is put into an array, which is used to build a new string.

Comment: Thanks Your method also proved Successfull

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
string _myString= "Apple Bat Cat";
myString= myString.Replace(" ", "");
```

**Output:** AppleBatCat

Also take a look at [String Replace Method MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx)

Comment: only it won't work on actual data, check actual code in question to see why.